# Why are terminal shortcuts different than the ones used elsewhere for the same task?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, usability

I ask this out of sheer curiosity.

For pasting - why wasn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> made as a shortcut - which is standard - instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> - which is not standard?

Same goes with so many other shortcuts (which are in common with other platforms). For scrolling up - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> instead of <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, as another example.

Since this is deliberate, of course, then I am sure there is a logical explanation for it?

Comment: What are these shortcuts supposed to do?

Comment: @Alvar: Ctrl+Shift+V pastes what is in the clipboard. Shift+PgUp scrolls up, I think.

Comment: The usage of `Ctrl-V` on Unix predates the GUI paste function from Xerox, I think. I suppose the same goes for the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts used by Terminal are not available for programs running in the Terminal. That's why Terminal tries not to use shortcuts that are standard among command line programs.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is a standard for "Insert verbatim", i.e. you can use for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> to insert a carriage return character (ASCII #13). It is used for example by Bash and some editors.

<kbd>PgUp</kbd> is used to scroll in text editors, pages and such, and people would likely get angry if that didn't work.

Comment: `CTRL`-`C` - Cancel that operation/Stop program run/Script, `CTRL`-`S` - Stop transmitting, `CTRL`-`X` - Start transmit. Generally `CTRL`-`A` equals the input of ASCII code 1, and `CTRL`-`Z` ASCII code 26 - and all the ones between in similar manner. Now all you have to to is look up an [ASCII code table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and decipher the codes in the lower part of the table. The short acronyms shown have (had) a meaning, some of it can still be seen in `man terminfo`.